# Export Table from HTMLto PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table and I want to export the data into pdf. I am trying to achieve this by using jquery. I have installed all library files. What is wrong with my code or did I miss any library files

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="classification" content="" />

        <!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE STYLE  -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script>

    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $("#pdf").click(function(e){
            $("#tablepdf").tableExport({
                type:'pdf',
                escape:'false'
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

<h2>Export Data to pdf with PHP and MySQL</h2>

<button type="submit" id="pdf"  class="btn btn-info">Export to pdf</button>

<table id="tablepdf" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
  </body>
    <!-- FOOTER SECTION END-->
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES PLACED AT THE BOTTOM TO REDUCE THE LOADING TIME  -->
    <!-- CORE JQUERY  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/tableExport.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- For PDF-->
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script><!-- This templates was made by Colorlib (https://colorlib.com) -->
</html>
```

When i click on the button it does not gives any reaction Library files required for this are already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I just left the jquery and I used this:

```
https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf
```

Its very simple to use and you can modify the whole look onto the pdf file.

Comment: Not helping that link .It looks complicated

Answer (score 0):

It seems script import order is not correct.

```
<!-- FOOTER SECTION END-->
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES PLACED AT THE BOTTOM TO REDUCE THE LOADING TIME  -->
    <!-- CORE JQUERY  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/tableExport.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- For PDF-->
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script><!-- This templates was made by Colorlib (https://colorlib.com) -->
```

I think, custom.js should be put in the end after importing PDF libraries

Comment: Then please try to convert it in back end and download generated PDF.

There are perfect libraries to convert HTML to PDF.

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Please try dompdf.